# Как помнять timezone с помощью moment.js?

Tags: javascript, дата

```
Я создал часы и подключил библиотеку moment.js, чтобы получить время. 

    var now = moment();
  var clock = document.getElementById("js-clock-content");

  moment.locale('en-gb');

  moment().tz.add("Europe/London");

  window.setInterval(function(){
    //clock.innerHTML = moment().tz("Europe/Berlin").format('HH:mm:ss');
  }, 1000);

Без timezone часы работают, но если подключить moment-timezone.js, уже появляются ошибки. 

Мне нужно поменять время на London. 

Все что нужно делать, так это поменять timezone для объекта moment(). 
Если прописать moment().tz.add("Europe/London"), то появляется ошибка

    jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: moment(...).tz.add is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js? [sm]:7)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Вот спинным мозгом чувствую что вы отдельно не подключили moment-timezone-with-data.js  или moment-timezone.min.js    ))

Comment: Вот 
<script src="assets/libs/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js"></script>

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Dr8KNglFkGyNzA

Answer (score 0):

```
Все наконец-то заработало. 
Нужно подключить moment-timezone-with-data.min.js перед moment.js

И в коде прописать следующее 

    var now = moment();
  var clock = document.getElementById("js-clock-content");

  moment.locale('en-gb');

  window.setInterval(function(){
    clock.innerHTML = moment().tz("Europe/London").format('HH:mm:ss');
  }, 1000);
```